# How to Transfer apps back to internal storage from sd card on android 7

Tags: applications

I moved some of my own downloaded apps to the sd card and now when I go to use them it says they are not installed and won't let me put them back into internal storage.  The 2 options pop up ie: sd card and internal but when I select internal, it does not accept it and leaves them on the card.  It is on my Samsung galaxy tab s2 model SM-T810 running Android 7.  Can anyone help me out please

Liz